# Controlling a Sony Bravia TV and sound bar with an Apple TV

Tags: audio, appletv, remote-control, television

hopefully, this is the right forum, for this question because I have no idea who else to ask.

I want my apple TV to control my TV and soundbar.  This includes sleep/wake functionality as well as volume and mute.

My soundbar can be connected by an optical cable or HDMI.  As I understand it, optical cables are incapable of passing signals (on/off/volume), and only pass data. based on what I have observed this appears to be true.  If I plug in the HDMI cable from HDMI2 on the TV to the HDMI3 port on the soundbar(Only port on the rear of the unit), it will turn on and off with the TV remote or the Apple TV remote and volume and mute controls work.  The only issue is, when I turn on the Apple TV, it signals the TV and soudbar to wake and sends a signal for the TV to switch to HDMI1 (The HDMI port that the Apple TV is plugged into).  The problem is that either the TV or the Apple TV is sending a signal to the soundbar, setting it to HDMI1.

If I unplug the HDMI cable between the TV and the soundbar, just using the optical cable, and set up custom IR controls for the soundbar in the Apple TV remotes menu, I am able to adjust sound and mute, but there is no other connectivity.  The good part is that the input does not change, but the bad part is that the Apple TV isn't able to turn on/off the soundbar.

This has to be a common configuration.  Has anyone else worked around this?

Comment: I've always considered the standard solution to this issue is to have a stack of disparate remotes, on each of which only two or three buttons is ever actually used.  I'm down to three these days (oh… & a bluetooth keyboard & trackpad), it used to be worse ;)

Comment: Get a [Logitech Harmony](https://www.myharmony.com/en-us/) remote. Although I don't have a sound bar, the Harmony remote controls a Sony Bravia TV, Sony receiver/amp, Sony BluRay disc player, Cable TV box and AppleTV. _Disclaimer:_ no financial or other ties to Logitech.

Comment: I "second" the Harmony suggestion.  We now have 4 of them.  People loved the "One" but the replacement was garbage (for me), so now we buy the cheaper 650, and I actually like it more than the One.  One of ours controls a soundbar, so unless yours is an extremely odd model, Harmony should be able to control it.

Comment: I’m just a little annoyed by the situation. An Apple TV costs 3 times as much as it’s competition, but a pay it anyway because I have something that is refined and just works. Yet in this case I can’t tweak a single signal it sends so my only options are to use two remotes or spend another 100 to put a band-aid on the issue.